# PostgreSQL remote connection on NAS Synology Diskstation DS216j

Tags: remote, postgresql, database, nas, synology

I have a postgreSQL database running on a NAS Synology Diskstation DS216j connected to my router. I want to be able to connect and use the database from a remote computer outside my LAN.

In order to do that I have set a port forwarding on my router to the NAS on ports:

- 5432 (Postgres)
- 5005 (Webdav)

If I check the ports of my public IP they are both open. If I check the ports on my NAS they are both open.

From a remote computer running Wndows platform I am able to connect to the database with pgAdmin III, and I have installed Netdrive which has WebDAV and I am able to see all the files on the NAS.

The problem is: when I launch the database (with LibreOffice Base), I cannot access it. After typing the user/password I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This looks like LibreOffice is attempting to connect to the private IP (192.168.0.20), when it needs to actually connect to the public IP.